# How to set up StatsD (along with Grafana & Graphite) as backend for Kamon?

Tags: scala, akka, statsd, grafana, akka-monitoring

I want to track [Akka](http://akka.io/) actor's metrics and for that I am using [Kamon](http://kamon.io/) a JVM monitoring tool, which requires a backend service to post it's stats data so for this purpose I've decided to use open source StatsD with the combination of Grafana & Graphite. Here is the Grafana [image](https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite) which I ran in the docker (with the help of docker tool since I am on Mac), everything thing is working fine. I am able to see Grafana UI screen but its showing some random data in the graphs, may be these are example graphs. Now I am struggling on how to configure it with my own datasource. If anybody here had same experience in the past, can help me? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random graphs you are seeing are the default grafana test datasource.

You first need to configure a new datasource that points at the Graphite metrics. The important thing to realise here is that the URL to the Graphite datasource from Grafana is located within the same Docker container i.e. the localhost.

If you set up a new datasource with the following properties:

- Name: graphite
- Default: checked
- Type: Graphite
- URL: http://localhost:8000
- Access: proxy

You should then have a datasource that points to the Graphite metric data within the Docker container.

Note - the default username/password for the Grafana UI is **admin/admin**.

Hope this helps.